# How to remove old html when appending new html content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using below code to append some data which getting from api

```
for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    //alert(d[i].food_name);
    $('#myModal .modal-body').append("<span>" + 
          d[i].food_name + "</span><span>" + 
          d[i].redeem_code + "</span><span 
          class='food_price'>" + d[i].food_price + " 
         </span><span class='food-check'><input value=" + 
          d[i].food_id + " type='radio' redeem=" + 
          d[i].redeem_code + " food-price=" + 
          d[i].food_price + " food_name="+ d[i].food_name 
          + " name='food' class='select'></span><br>");
}
```

When the api is hitting second time the old data is also showing with new data. To solve this I tried with `.html()` but using this only the last record is showing. Please help. Not getting it.

Comment: remove the append() and use html(). If you have more elements then give the $('#myModal .modal-body').html("") before starting the for loop

Comment: by html() the only last record is showing in modal

Comment: i edited my comment check it

Comment: @KarthiKeyan. I'm getting 6 records from the api when i use .html(). Only the last record from the api is showing.

Comment: either give .html("") before the loop or give .html("") if (i==0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the html *before* you go into the loop. So keep the append, but use the below *before* the loop:

```
$('#myModal .modal-body').empty();
```

See [this JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvk2908x/) as an example.

Answer (score 2):

use .empty() to empty content in a element

```
$('#myModal .modal-body').empty().append()
```

Comment: Doing this will have the same effect as using `html()` instead of `append()`. It will only display the last record.

Comment: Let me check it

Comment: Yes it's displaying last record only

Answer (score 1):

Use `.html("")` instead of `.html()`  to clear innerhtml of your selected DOM.

And about your question.

```
Var newHtml=" ";
For(loop)
{
newHtml= newHtml+ "your data[i]";
}
OldHtml.html(" ");

OldHtml.html(newHtml);
```

The above code will append new data to your html.

Comment: what is differece in it?. Can you please explain?

Comment: .html() is a selector. For example div.html() mean you are want to select inner html of div. But div.html(" <p>new tag</p>") append new html to div. or not i didnt undrestand your question and im sorry.

Comment: let me check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method, it replaces selected elements with new content.

You need to store the html in a variable while iterating through and can replace the element.

```
let html = '';
for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    html += `<span> ${d[i].food_name} </span>
            <span> ${d[i].redeem_code}</span>
            <span class='food_price'> ${d[i].food_price} </span>
            <span class='food-check'>
                <input value=" ${d[i].food_id} type='radio' redeem='${d[i].redeem_code}' food-price= ${d[i].food_price} food_name="${d[i].food_name} name='food' class='select'>
            </span>
        <br>`
}
$('#myModal .modal-body').replaceWith(html);
```